# How to fit the screen without scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm using bootstrap to create layout.

This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body{
                background-color: #000000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border: 1px solid #373737;">
                    <canvas></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border: 1px solid #373737;">
                    <canvas></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border: 1px solid #373737;">
                    <canvas></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border: 1px solid #373737;">
                    <canvas></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border: 1px solid #373737;">
                    <canvas></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border: 1px solid #373737;">
                    <canvas></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border: 1px solid #373737;">
                    <canvas></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border: 1px solid #373737;">
                    <canvas></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is how to fit the screen without scroll. because, i have divide the two col-sm-6 in each row it's created the 2 column's x 4 row's the size of width is ok. but, The height is high. so, browser automatically show scrollbar vertically. how to decrease height and how to fit the screen.[image]

Comment: This wont be that use friendly. But you can still try giving a height of 100vh to your main div containing rows and columns.

Comment: I tried but, no difference

Comment: You should really, I mean _really_, use CSS files instead of repeating inline styles. And @Rahul is right, setting `height:100vh` to your main div will force it to use all of viewport's height.

Answer (score 0):

By default the canvas element takes width of 300px and height of 150px if not mentioned. Bootstrap has no impacts on height. 
Specify the height of canvas in order to adjust height

Comment: My aim is how to scale to fit inside browser screen.

Comment: And how exactly would OP do that?

Comment: You need to attach listener to canvas element for resizing. Canvas element expects height and width and wont work without that. So consider adding listener to modify width and height of canvas dynamically on screen size change and on load of page.

Comment: @JeremyThille Could you please explain what is OP?

Comment: OP = Original Poster, that's a generic term on the internet to indicate the author of a post or a question.

Comment: @user3214224: FYR , you can see this fiddle for resizing canvas
http://jsfiddle.net/bc3z6ot3/1/

Answer (score -1):

Setting `height:100vh` to your main container will force it to use all available area in the viewport.

Live demo (turn it fullscreen) :

```css
body,html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.fullscreen {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #add8e6;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen">
 Any content in here
</div>
```